# How to wait for user input before creating embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a quick question regarding my code below. I am trying to gather user input to build up an embed, however it is creating the embed right away and not waiting for awaitMessage to finish. Is there anyway to solve this and what is the reason for this? I know I can just put the embed code inside the `.then` block, but I want to keep it outside as I am going to be collecting additional user input.

Thanks for any help!

```js
message.author.send(
 'Lets get to work!\nPlease enter the title of your event. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)'
);
message.channel
 .awaitMessages(
  (response) =>
   response.author.id === message.author.id && response.content.length < 10,
  {
   max: 1,
   time: 10000,
   errors: ['time'],
  }
 )
 .then((collected) => {
  message.author.send(`I collected the message : ${collected.first().content}`);
  let title = collected.first().content;
 })
 .catch(() => {
  message.author.send('No message collected after 10 seconds.');
 });

const eventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setColor('RANDOM')
 .setTitle(title)
 .setAuthor(message.author.username)
 .setDescription('help')
 .setImage();
message.channel.send(eventEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to continue inside the callback, you can put it in a function.

```js
const sendSomething = () => {
  message.author.send(
    "Lets get to work!\nPlease enter the title of your event. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)"
  );
  message.channel
    .awaitMessages(
      (response) =>
        response.author.id === message.author.id &&
        response.content.length < 10,
      {
        max: 1,
        time: 10000,
        errors: ["time"],
      }
    )
    .then((collected) => {
      message.author.send(
        `I collected the message : ${collected.first().content}`
      );
      let title = collected.first().content;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      message.author.send("No message collected after 10 seconds.");
    });
};

await sendSomething()

// do something after
```

---

#### Code Snippet Demonstration:

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('Success!'), 2000); // delay 2 seconds to simulate awaiting a message
});

promise1.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

console.log('This will execute before, even though it is positioned after');
```

```js
const newFunction = () => { // create it in a function
  const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Success!'), 2000); // delay 2 seconds to simulate awaiting a message
  });

  return promise1.then((res) => { // return the promise callback
    console.log(res);
  });
};

// both `.then()` and `await` will work
newFunction().then(() => console.log('This will execute after, *and* is positioned after'));
```

Comment: Hi (again! haha). I am a bit confused but I think what you are showing me to do is go about making an async function or using promises? I've been researching along that route after looking at your response.

Comment: The the promise function is just taking the place of the `awaitMessages()` function, as they both return a promise